# Split the string and save it into a list orderly in python

Tags: python, string, list, split

In the codes,result shows "['fi', 'lou', 'you']".But i want to split the string "fi lou you",and save 'fi' in a[0], 'lou' in a[1],'you' in a[2].How can i achieve it.

```
a=['fi lou you'.split()]
print(a[0])
```

Comment: `a='fi lou you'.split()`. `split` returns a `list`. If you cast it to list on top, it will become nested.

Comment: Yeah, my skills on reading document truly should be  strengthened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation of [`string.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) you can see that it returns a *list*. You are then encapsulating the result of this in another list using square brackets, `[]` which produces a *nested* list.

The solution would be to simply remove the square brackets when splitting the string

```
a='fi lou you'.split()
print(a[0])  
# fi
```

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for

```
>>>a = "fi lou you".split()
>>> a
['fi', 'lou', 'you']
>>> a[0]
'fi'
>>> a[1]
'lou'
>>> a[2]
'you'
>>>
```

or there is something more complicated?

Comment: It  resolves my question  perfectly too.But the DavidG put the resolution  in the earlier time.So i vote the reply of  him.Thank you very much

Answer (score -2):

Used this technique to get your desired response.

```
    a = "['fi', 'lou', 'you']" # This is the input string
    a = a.replace("[","").replace("]","").split()
    print a[0]
```

Comment: most likely because the input string you're using is very different from the one OP is using and your output is not the result OP desired either.